# How to unlock a rwlock without dropping the lock

Tags: rust

How to unlock a rwlock? I can't drop the lock since i need it more than 1 time. I have some code like this:

```
struct Abc {
    lock: RwLock<()>,
    data: usize,
}

let a = Abc {
    RwLock::new(()),
    data: 0,
};

a.lock.read().unwrap();
// do something with data
// now i need to unlock a.lock so others threads can use it
```

Comment: Can you show some more code showing what you're having trouble with. I think you may be misunderstanding how a `RwLock` works. It is its members `read` and `write` that return a Result containing a`RwLockReadGuard` or `RwLockWriteGuard` that perform the locking and unlocking, not the `RwLock`s `drop`.

Comment: I edited my question to add some more code about how I use it. By RwLockReadGuard/RwLockWriteGuard, do you mean that the lock will auto unlock when the Guards is dropped?

Comment: " do you mean that the lock will auto unlock when the Guards is dropped?" - Yes.

Comment: Read the document carefully and released that i misunderstood about RwLock and Guards.

Answer (score 0):

As @Michael Anderson said, the RwLock is unlocked when the guards is dropped, not the RwLock itself.